# Retrieve name from SQL - Unexpected error "Impossible to convert int to string"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to get the name of the user that added the last record from the db.
The query is correct but I get the error **"impossible to convert type "int" to "string"**. The type of data in the db is a varchar.
What am I doing wrong?

```
  protected void LastProject()
     {
         string lastProjUser = "SELECT name FROM Users WHERE uname = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)";
         string getconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stad_conn"].ConnectionString;
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring);
         using (SqlCommand lastProjUserName
         = new SqlCommand(lastProjUser, conn))
         {
             conn.Open();
             lastProjUserName.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
             string name = (string)lastProjUserName.ExecuteNonQuery();  //ERROR IS HERE
             Label3.Text = name;
             conn.Close();
         }
     }
```

**UPDATE**
Table "Projects" from the highest "id" I need to know the "uname"
Table "Users" I need the "name" associated to the "username" which is the uname from table "Projects"

Table Projects:

```
[id]                       INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[proj_id]                  VARCHAR (20)    NULL,
[proj_prod_id]             VARCHAR (20)    NULL,
[uname]                    VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
```

Table Users

```
[id]        INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[name]      VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[username]  VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[pass]      VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
```

Comment: Looks like you are returning max Id(int) from Projects and using that as name(varchar) to look up in the Users table - that seems like a conflict in data type. Are you able to execute the query in the Sql Management studio?

Comment: That schema makes no sense; why do you have both a Project.id and Project.proj_id? Why is there a uname in Projects? There is no relation between Users and Projects, you should get rid of Projects.uname and add Projects.user_id. Please tell me Users.pass is not really a user password...

Comment: @DourHighArch I am trying to sort out someone else code. Having a lot to do on it. However, uname in Project is exactly "username" in users. Therefore is like an inner-joint maxID-uname/name-username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database schema is very badly designed, but if that's what you're stuck with you can try:

```
SELECT uname FROM Projects WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a name field with an id field, did you mean to do that?

Comment: I am looking for username associated with the highest "id" in table project and trying to get the name of the user in table users associated with the username.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** consider changing your query as it is not valid comparing `id` column(`int`) with `name` column(`varchar`) does not serve your purpose.
**2.** you need to call `ExecuteReader()` not `ExecuteNonQuery()` when running `Select` query.

```
        SqlDataReader reader=lastProjUserName.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read())
        string name = reader["name"].ToString();
```

**3.**  if you have `id` column in `users` table and if it is referring to `projects` table `id` column using `primary key` &  `foreign key` relationship you can use following `query`

```
"SELECT name FROM Users WHERE id= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)";
```

**Complete code:**

```
    protected void LastProject()
         {
             string lastProjUser = "SELECT name FROM Users WHERE id= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)";
             string getconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stad_conn"].ConnectionString;
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring);
             using (SqlCommand lastProjUserName = new SqlCommand(lastProjUser, conn))
             {
                 conn.Open();
                 lastProjUserName.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                 SqlDataReader reader=lastProjUserName.ExecuteReader();
                 if(reader.Read())
                 {
                 string name = reader["name"].ToString();    
                 Label3.Text = name;
                 } 
                conn.Close();
             }
         }
```

Comment: @FeliceM : can you please tell me your users table columns?

Comment: I am working on it. Looks like you are correct but I need to sort out the query. I come back now now.

Comment: @FeliceM : check my edited answer with 3rd point if you satify 3rd point in my answer then it works perfectly. try with Complete code.

Comment: Thanks, error is solved but I get no results jet. I am not sure if your answer came before or after I added the tables in my question.

Comment: @FeliceM : no issues , could you please edit your question with latest code you are trying.

Comment: @FeliceM : please check `Complete Code` now and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL statement should read

```sql
SELECT name
FROM Users
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)
```

(`WHERE id = ...` instead of `WHERE name = ...`).

---

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of records affected. It's not what you want. Use `ExecuteScalar` instead.

```cs
string name = (string)lastProjUserName.ExecuteScalar();
```

`ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row returned by your query.

---

**UPDATE**

If I take into account your latest edits I get:

```sql
SELECT
    u.name
FROM
    Users u
    INNER JOIN Projects p
        ON u.username = p.uname
WHERE
    p.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)
```

Comment: There is also an error in the SQL command text. You are comparing the name with the maximum id.

Comment: Olivier, I agree on the use of SelectScalar, initially I did it. however, I cannot get out the name of the user. Looks like the statement need an inner joint that I am unable to define. I have updated my question with the db tables.

Answer (score 0):

change lastProjUser  like this:

```
"SELECT name FROM Users WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Projects)"
```

Comment: how about this: string name = lastProjUserName.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();

Comment: @masoumehkarvar : he is executing select command so he has to execute either `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecuteReader()`.